# Find the terms in a sequence in terms of the initial elements given the recurrence relation

Tags: maxima

Summary: I have a `k`-th order recurrence relation, and I need to find the terms `a[n]` in terms of `a[0], a[1], ..., a[k-1]`

---

Consider this recurrence relation:

```
2*(n+2)*(n+1)*a[n+2] + 3*(n+1)*a[n+1] + (n+3)*a[n] = 0
```

Since this is a second order homogeneous linear recurrence relation, each `a[n]` can be expressed as a linear combination of `a[0]` and `a[1]`:

```
a[n] = c0[n] * a[0] + c1[n] * a[1]
```

Where `c0[n]` and `c1[n]` are some constants. I am trying to find `a[n]` in the form above (having only `a[0]` and `a[1]` from the sequence).

---

This is how I defined the recurrence in Maxima:

```
rec: 2*(n+2)*(n+1)*a[n+2] + 3*(n+1)*a[n+1] + (n+3)*a[n] = 0;

eqns: makelist(''rec, n, 0, 6);
```

[image: output of commands above]

My current approach is setting `a[0]` to `0` and `a[1]` to `1` to find the coefficients of `a[1]` and vice versa:

```
c0 = solve(append(eqns, [a[0] = 1, a[1] = 0]));

c1 = solve(append(eqns, [a[0] = 0, a[1] = 1]));
```

[image: output of commands above]

This works fine, and I get the coefficients. But I wonder how I can tell Maxima that `a[0]` and `a[1]` are the unknowns, and it should find, e.g. `a[2]`, in terms of `a[0]` and `a[1]`.

Comment: I found the solution after I finished writing the question, I am posting it anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell Maxima that you want to solve for `a[2], a[3], ..., a[n]`:

```
eqns: makelist(''rec, n, 0, 6);

unknowns: makelist(a[i], i, 2, 8);

solve(eqns, unknowns);
```

[image: result of the commands above]